# Where is the Dockerfile (or build) for the official tensorflow/tensorflow:2.xx-gpu Docker images?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am trying to build a GPU-enabled Docker image for my ML application, but I have some fairly strict requirements:

- `tensorflow==2.13`
- `python>=3.10,<3.12`

The [tensorflow/tensorflow:2.13.0-gpu image on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/2.13.0-gpu/images/sha256-b4676741c491bff3d0f29c38c369281792c7d5c5bfa2b1aa93e5231a8d236323?context=explore) is based on Ubuntu 20.04 so use a quite old Python 3.8.

There is also [tensorflow/build:2.13-python3.11](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/build/2.13-python3.11/images/sha256-0096f4f2264b6dd93d70fd06790a04e2bed089bbec2dbcf6b726dddcdbf9f402?context=explore) that technically works great, but is a whopping 11GB.  I guess I am hoping to get an image closer to the 6.6GB that `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.13.0-gpu` clocks in at, but with a newer Python.  (I acknowledge even this is huge, and most of that is from GPU support)

Is there an extant public (and trusted) Docker image that meets my needs?

Otherwise I could try to build my own. In this case I would like to replicate and slightly modify the same build behind `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.13.0-gpu`, but I am not sure where that lives.  (It did not have luck just reproducing the commands shown in `docker history`.)  Where is the Dockerfile (or build script) for the official tensorflow/tensorflow:2.13-gpu Docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the code to build `tensorflow/tensorflow` runtime images here: https://github.com/tensorflow/build/tree/fdd023e/tensorflow_runtime_dockerfiles

I was able to successfully build a new image with my own choice of Python version and Tensorflow as follows:

1. Clone the repo
2. `docker build -f gpu.Dockerfile --target=base --build-arg="TENSORFLOW_PACKAGE=tensorflow~=2.13.0" . -t tensorflow/custom-runtime:2.13-python3.11`